# How does Safari's reader feature work?

Tags: safari

I want to add a similar feature to a tool I'm making. I'm interested in how it works code-wise. I want to be able get an html page and exclude all but the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Readability project does something similar for chrome and iOS. I'm not sure how it detects the content automatically but I know that Readability has an API for people who want to integrate it's features. You might want to check that out.

http://www.readability.com/learn-more

Comment: Thanks. This look similar to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Ruby, you could use [Pismo](https://github.com/peterc/pismo). It extracts an article from a given document.